# Transform an object with objects in it

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following key/value object

```
form: {
  id: {value: this.item.id, hidden: true},
  title: {value: this.item.title},
  translations: {
    en: {
      locale: {value: 'en', hidden: true},
      name: {value: 'Hello World'}
    },
    nl: {
      locale: {value: 'nl', hidden: true},
      name: {value: 'Hallo Wereld'}
    }
  }
}
```

So each key has an object with a value and a hidden attribute, I'm stuck on how to achieve the following.
**Transform the nested object so each key just has it's value. Not the object with value and hidden.** The big issue it seems for me is that it's nested.. So it has to work recursive.

This is the desired end result

```
form: {
  id: this.item.id,
  title: this.item.title,
  translations: {
    en: {
      locale: 'en',
      name: 'Hello World'
    },
    nl: {
      locale: 'nl',
      name: 'Hallo Wereld'
    }
  }
}
```

#### I've tried

Using a combination of Object.keys(form).map(...), which gives me the key of each item, but that's not going to work recursive I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the typo, Mamun, it's fixed now.

Comment: Obtaining the value from keys and checking for typeOf and if that results to object, then get the keys for that object perhaps?

Comment: All values are objects, as you can see in my first code block.

Comment: Make a recursive function that takes an object as a parameter. Loop over keys and check if it is an object then call the function with the new object as parameter

Comment: I may be wrong but I dont think lines like `this.item.id` & `this.item.title` & so on will actually work. Self referencing during object initializing seems dont work

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```js
function transform(obj) {
  return Object.entries(obj).reduce((newObj, [name, value]) => ({ ...newObj, [name]: value.value === undefined ? transform(value) : value.value  }), {})
}

const form = {
  id: {value: '77777', hidden: true},
  title: {value: '11111'},
  translations: {
    en: {
      locale: {value: 'en', hidden: true},
      name: {value: 'Hello World'}
    },
    nl: {
      locale: {value: 'nl', hidden: true},
      name: {value: 'Hallo Wereld'}
    }
  }
}

console.log(transform(form))
```

Explanation:

```js
function transform(obj) {
  const entries = Object.entries(obj) // transform object to Array<[propertyName, propertyValue]>

  const tranformedObject = entries.reduce(reducer, {}) // inital value for the first arg of reducer is {}

  return tranformedObject
}

function reducer(newObj, [propertyName, propertyValue]) { // name 
  return {
    ...newObj, // get all properties (that we already set) from prev newObj
    [propertyName]: propertyValue.value === undefined ? transform(propertyValue) : propertyValue.value // if property has .value use it or use recursively tranformed object
  }  // returned value will be set to newObj, and than returned to tranformedObject
}
```

`{ ...prop, [name]: vaue }` - it's [ES6 syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)

Comment: If you have time, feel free to explain, annotate the code!

Comment: @Notflip check out

Comment: Strangly enough I'm getting "Maximum call stack size exceeded", I changed some data but it's very similar. I think there's an infinite loop with the || transform(value), and it's to do with the Translations object: https://imgur.com/a/PPPYT5B

Comment: Ok found the issue, when a field has empty string or 0, it also passes as undefined.. and triggers a re-run of transform.

Comment: Edited the answer to reflect this change!

Comment: @Notflip the best way is to check it using `value.hasOwnProperty("value")`

Comment: Ah, good advice, what's the difference? Feel free to edit my edit again

Comment: value can be set as undefined) using `.value === undefined` you can't handle it, but `.hasOwnProperty("value")` handles it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about performance of this solution, but it's really small

```js
function transform(obj) {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj, (key, value) => "value" in value ? value.value : value))
}

const form = {
  id: {value: '77777', hidden: true},
  title: {value: '11111'},
  translations: {
    en: {
      locale: {value: 'en', hidden: true},
      name: {value: 'Hello World'}
    },
    nl: {
      locale: {value: 'nl', hidden: true},
      name: {value: 'Hallo Wereld'}
    }
  }
}

console.log(transform(form))
```

Explanation: `JSON.stringify` accepts `replacer` parameter which can be used to transform any value as you want

// My mind was blown when i figured this solution

Comment: @Notflip what do you think about my solution? 